# Question marks when compile C source codes using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

We got many question marks ? in the compilation messages as follows when we use gcc to compile our C source. Could you help us, thanks! We used gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48).

```
[source]$ gcc -g -Wall my_c_source.c -o my_c_source
In file included from my_c_source.c:38:
my_c_source.h: In function ?.rint_result?.
my_c_source.h:554: warning: format ?.i?.expects type ?.nt?. but argument 3 has type ?.ong int?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your locale settings are probably inconsistent with your terminal settings.

gcc uses non-ASCII ‘ (left single quotation mark) and ’ (right single quotation mark) characters in its error messages. Apparently your locale settings are telling gcc that those characters can be used, but your terminal settings are such that they don't show up correctly -- or perhaps you have a font that doesn't support those characters.

If possible, configure your terminal emulator to use UTF-8.

If you can't do that, then setting the `$LANG` environment variable to "C" will tell gcc to use the ASCII apostrophe character instead:

```
$ LANG=C gcc -g -Wall my_c_source.c -o my_c_source
```